# Loop repeating itself?

Tags: c, clion

I am currently trying to teach myself C since I believe that will be a good segue into C++ and C# (as well as getting a headstart prior to the start of classes). So I have decided to write this loop here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    bool continueLoop = true;
    char response;
    printf("ARE YOU READY TO RUMBLE?!?!\n Y/N\n");
    response = getchar();
    int counter = 0;

        do
        {
            counter++;
            if (response == 'Y')
            {
                printf("AWESOME!");
                continueLoop == false;
                return 0;
            }
            else if (response == 'N')
            {
                printf("YOU FAIL!");
                continueLoop == false;
                return 0;
            }
           if (continueLoop == true)
            {
                printf("I do not understand your input!\n");
                printf("Please reinput! Y/N\n");
                response = getchar();
            }
            if(counter == 5)
            {
                printf("Exiting!");
                continueLoop == false;
                goto exit;
            }
        }while (continueLoop == true);

    exit:
        return 0;
}
```

My question(s) is(are) as follows: Why is it when if I input for example 'M' as my answer, it will loop itself twice; however if it is given the proper condition then terminates correctly.

Also, instead of `getchar()` should I instead convert response into a single length of array and then try to compare it somehow, or perhaps it should be done via the printf statement as so `printf("ARE YOU READY TO RUMBLE?!? \n %s", response);`

If it helps, I am using C-Lion as my IDE as I refuse to write any code in vi, emacs, or notepad.

**EDITED CODE**

```
int main()
{


    char response;
    printf("ARE YOU READY TO RUMBLE?!?!\n Y/N\n");
    scanf(" %c", &response);

    int counter = 0;


    while (counter < 5)
    {
        counter++;
        if (response == 'Y')
        {
            printf("AWESOME!");

            return 0;
        }
        else if (response == 'N')
        {
            printf("YOU FAIL!");

            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("I do not understand your input!\n");
            printf("Please reinput! Y/N\n");
            response = getchar();
        }

    }


    return 0;


}
```

Comment: You press two keys when you enter `M`. That is why the loop executes twice. And use == when you want to *compare* two things and *=* when you want to assign two things. Also using `goto` us considered as bad practise. You can replace the `goto` with `break ` in this case.

Comment: Side note: `while (continueLoop)` is enough.

Comment: .... the second key, as per *Cool Guy*'s comment, is the Enter-key.

Comment: `getchar()` waits for a newline, and returns the letter you entered the first time, then returns the newline.  Also never do `while (continueLoop == true)`. Just use `while (continueLoop)`, because C considers all non-zero values to be true.

Comment: Also, the `goto exit;` is completely unnecessary once you fix your typo on the line before it, `continueLoop == false;` --> `continueLoop = false;` (single '=')

Comment: Also this question is a duplicate to dozens of other question.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker `getchar(3)` does not wait for anything. It's the terminal device driver that makes input available line-by-line, so stdio blocks waiting for input until a newline is entered and the terminal driver flushes the input queue. This can be changed with `tcsetattr(3)` by disabling `ICANON` (canonical mode). But note that stdio will still use line-buffered input and output when it is reading from and writing to a terminal device; this can also be changed with `setvbuf(3)`.

Comment: Use `==` to check for equality, but just `=` to assign a value... they're not interchangeable.

Comment: To use `bool` you have to `#include <stdbool.h>`. If your code works without that, you are not compiling for C, but C++. Do not!. These are different languages.

Comment: You should try single-stepping through it in a debugger so you can understand the the flow of execution... you don't need the `goto` or the extra `return`s if you fix the other mistakes -- it looks like they were added because the loop didn't do what you expected..

Comment: Looks like it is indeed C++ code i suppose since I have not been using stdbool.h. I do have to say though, the compiler often complains of unreachable code, and I am not even sure why that would be the case. I suppose I may have to transition over to a notepad editor, as C-lion seems to be causing quite a few issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you input `M`, you're not really inputting `M` only; you are inputting `M` followed by a newline. So `getchar(3)` will return `M` when you first call it, and then it will return `\n` on the second call. Hence the loop executes twice.

You can capture input and ignore whitespaces (newlines, tabs, spaces, etc) with `scanf(" %c", &response)`. Note the leading whitespace in the format string; it is required to force `scanf(3)` to skip blanks.

Also these statements inside the first two if's are useless:

```
continueLoop == false;
```

You compare `continueLoop` to `false` and then throw the result away (if you're not compiling with `-Wall`, you should because this will very likely give you a warning).

You probably want assignment instead of comparison:

```
continueLoop = false;
```

Comment: Hmm, that is true, didn't notice the incorrect sign. So I have decided to change that, and also I changed my printf statement to be as follows: **printf("ARE YOU READY TO RUMBLE?!?!\n Y/N \n %c", &response);** I am still facing the same issue, did I improperly edit it?

Comment: @Ageoffan You can't do both things with `printf(3)`. `printf(3)` writes output, `scanf(3)` reads input. Leave `printf(3)` as it was before, and after `printf(3)`, replace `response = getchar();` with `scanf(" %c", &response);`.

Comment: I see, didn't notice that it was scanf. So just to confirm, am I currently editing it properly? **char response;
    printf("ARE YOU READY TO RUMBLE?!?!\n Y/N\n");
    scanf(" %c", &response);**

Comment: Still repeating itself oddly enough, I am wondering though if my code is actually C++ instead of just C since one of the comments mention how if my code works without the #include <bool> then it is actually C++. My code does work without since the IDE is a C/C++ IDE. That being said though, I am still not positive why that would occur.

Comment: @Ageoffan You still have `response = getchar();` in the `else` inside the loop. You need to replace that with `scanf(" %c", &response);` as well, like you did before.

Comment: Omg, thank you soo much. Can't believe I missed something soo small. +1 for you for certain. If I may ask, when would one use a getchar() then?

Comment: @Ageoffan There are various use cases. For example, you might use it to copy a file: you would read the file byte by byte with `getchar()` or the more generic `getc()` and write each character read with `putchar()` (or the more generic `putc()`). You surely don't want to ignore spaces when copying, so that is a good use case. Another example: you can use it to implement scanf's behavior to ignore whitespace: call `getchar()` in a loop until either it returns something that is not a whitespace or `EOF`. There are a lot of use cases, but in your scenario it just wasn't the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

better to use `scanf("%c",&ch);` instead of `getchar()` because it will return '\n' second time when you call . else other code looks fine .

As, one of my friend pointed out the same behaviour for scanf is same. then you can use getc

```
c = getc(stdin);
```

Comment: `scanf(3)` drops the usual whitespace skipping with `%c`. This will have the exact same effect.

Comment: When you say scanf(3), is that how I am supposed to write it (which I assume not since that will throw an error) or is that the forced location it needs to pick stuff?

Comment: @Ageoffan No, it's just a notation. UNIX manpages are divided into sections; the number in parentheses indicates the section where the help and description of `scanf` lives. It means that you can read about `scanf` in section 3 of the manpages with `man 3 scanf` (section 3 is for library calls). In the case of `scanf`, `man scanf` and `man 3 scanf` are equivalent, but sometimes there are commands with the same name as functions, and so you may need to specify which command / section you are interested in.

Comment: @Ageoffan Thus in the UNIX world people refer to functions or commands with the section number in parentheses to make it clear what they are talking about. You may see which sections are available in your system with `man man` (i,e. read the manpage for `man`).

Answer (score -2):

You have several mistakes in your code.

first if you want to repeat something `N` amount of times, use a `for` loop, instead of a `while`.
Second if you want to interrupt the loop early, try using a `break`, instead of a boolean.
Finally its redundant to change the boolean to false and then `return 0;`, since you're exiting the function.

```
int main() 
{
    char response;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("ARE YOU READY TO RUMBLE?!?!\n Y/N\n");
        response = getchar();
        if (response == 'Y' || response == 'y')
        {
            printf("AWESOME!");
            break;
        }
        else if (response == 'N' || response == 'n') 
        {
            printf("YOU FAIL!");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("I do not understand your input!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question at all.

Comment: I do appreciate the code, however for some reason my compiler says that the i++ is unreachable code? I am wondering if its a C-lion issue at this point.

Comment: move that int i from for loop , declare i to the top