# Why while, do-while and for loops are not working?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, cycle, do-while

Loop makes only a single iteration. It gives me 105.0 every single time, and it's supposed to do more iterations than just a single one. Also, I need to write more details because "my post is mostly code", but I can't say anything else because there's anything else to say, I guess.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Esercizio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int giorniDieciAnni, mesiDieciAnni, anniDieciAnni;
        giorniDieciAnni = 365*10;
        mesiDieciAnni = 12*10;
        anniDieciAnni = 10;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Interessatoio!");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Scrivi un saldo, un interesse, e calcolero':");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Interesse annuale: una volta l'anno, per 10 anni.");
        System.out.println("Interesse mensile: una volta al mese, per 10 anni.");
        System.out.println("Interesse giornaliero: una volta al giorno per 10 anni.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Scrivi un importo per il saldo: massimo due cifre decimali.");
        System.out.println("");

        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
        double saldo, interesse, saldoAnnuale = 0, valoreInteresse = 0;
        saldo = tastiera.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Inserire ora un tasso di interesse: massimo due cifre decimali.");
        System.out.println("");

        interesse = tastiera.nextDouble();
        valoreInteresse = ((saldo/100)*interesse);
        int conteggio = 1;

        do {
            saldoAnnuale = (saldo + valoreInteresse); 
            conteggio++;
            } while (conteggio <= 10);

        System.out.println("Saldo Annuale Prova: " + saldoAnnuale);


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? please explain more and syntax of for loop is not correct.

Comment: do and while depend on how you initialize count; for loop needs semicolons instead of commas.

Comment: Post a minimal compilable code so that we can reproduce the problem you are facing to give you a solution. Those _cycles_ are known as `loop` where one should write `for (; ;)` instead of `for (, ,)`.

Comment: Add some kind of error message

Comment: cycles = loops. This is not grammar, you just made me correct a synonim, but ok. The so-called loops iterate one time then stop, but they shouldn't stop iterating.

Comment: @Monok myself, and TJ have tried to assist you often and pointed out important points. Read them, understand them, and try understanding HOW your code works, use a debugger if need be

Answer (score 2):

your for loop needs to look like this:

```
for (int count = 0; count <= 10; count++) {
doSomething;  }
```

As for both of your while loops, you need to make sure that you declare a variable outside of the loop. Think of a while loop as though it is a for loop.

in a for loop we have three important elements the initial controlling variable, a limiter, and a incrementer.

We have the same structure in while loops. However, a while loop unpacks these things.

```
int variable = 0;
while(variable < 10)
{
//10 is the controller here
doSomething();
}
```

Edit: I would highly recommend that, when you are writing code, write it inside of an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ. Do not listen to what teachers or other folk who tell you about how vital it is to write code inside of a text editor like vi/vim. It is dumb, pointless, and won't teach you anything. If you were to use an IDE you would have found out the error right away. Also, make sure you understand how loop structures work.

Edit 2: The following view examples are of functional for/while loops that I have written both during work and for fun. Pro tip, do-while loops are utterly pointless in the vast majority of cases.

For Loop Example:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                          {
         //TODO: CREATE PROPER LOGIC GATES HERE
         if(rows.get(j).getAttribute("name").contains("P") && currentTime.contains("P"))
                 {
                            logger.info("Both times are still PM.");
                                     assert Integer.parseInt(rows.get(j).getAttribute("name").substring(0, 2).trim()) > currentTimeInt;
                 }
                 else if(rows.get(j).getAttribute("name").contains("A") && currentTime.contains("P"))
                    {
                                     logger.info("Time at index " + j + " is now AM compared to our current PM time which is: " + parseRows.get(3).getAttribute("name"));
                                     assert true;
                     }
             }
```

**Formating is kinda off**

While Loop Example:

```
counter = 0;
while(counter < 10)
{
   counter++;
   System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Edit Answer: I see that you do have your conteggio declared outside. However, the reason your thing prints only once is becauseL ** IT IS OUTSIDE OF THE LOOP** So your loop is fine, it is how you call the Saldo Annuale that's different. if you want to  be called on each iteration then you need to do the following:

```
do {
            saldoAnnuale += (saldo + valoreInteresse); 
            conteggio++;
            System.out.println("Saldo Annuale Prova: " + saldoAnnuale);
    } while (conteggio <= 10);
```

Comment: I have tried this, and still it doesn't work. Also stop taking "doSomething" seriously, it's just the shortest way to say that this loops does something else, and not just...be a loop without instructions.

Comment: @Monok: The *useful* way is `/*...do something...*/` or `doSomething();` so the code doesn't look like it has blatant errors other than the `,` vs. `;` one.

Comment: Okay, first question @Monok is this actual Java code that you posted. If so, please post your whole code, there may be something missing. Because your code, assuming you corrected your for loop and properly declare count outside of the while loop should work.

Comment: Why did you put the prinln inside of the loop, exactly...? It HAS to be outside...it's just a test...prova means test in italian, sort of...just leave it outside!

Comment: Mate, why are you shouting or angry? We are trying to assist you. You provided us with very little data. Now, you can indeed remove the Sys.out if you want and keep the rest of the loop. When you have code issues, make sure to clearly define what you Expect, what is the actual result, and what maybe the issue. Also, SO is an English site and a good amount of people do not speak Spanish/Latin

Comment: @Monok: ^^^ What Ageoffan said. Lose the attitude. You've certainly gone on *my* "don't bother with this guy in the future" list. (Ageoffan: It's Italian.)

Comment: Mate, I'm not shouting, nor I'm angry at all, you all are just answering questions no one answered, and you all did not answer my question. I've only repeated "Check the loops, something is wrong with them" all the time in different ways. And this is Italian, but my teacher told me that any coder can use whatever language/words to describe the variables, the names of them doesn't change how people read the program.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, no worries, I'm still trying to understand what's your problem with every single piece of my code, and why you claim yourself so good and big but can't even understand such a basic code. But hey, not all the people in this world are like me or you, so peace: no one cares about fighting here, just chill...I needed help, thanks anyway for the answers.

Comment: But we did answer your code, @Monok, we answered you issue often times. Your code is functional. As I said, look at the answers provided. SO is here to help, but ppl try to nudge you the right way if the solution is rather simple.

Comment: @Monok: *"you claim yourself so good and big but can't even understand such a basic code."* That, right there, is what I mean by "attitude." Quick reality check for you: It is not everyone else who is the problem here.

Comment: @Ageoffan, I'm asking for a solution because I clearly can't understand it by myself...even if it is "that easy", I'm learning Java since a month, and damn it, I find it hard. I can't figure out the solution. I came here for it, not for suggestions, and I tried to make it clear.

Comment: Okay, once again. Your while loop seems fine (and we explained the issue already btw). Your loop doesn't only do it once, it will continue its 10 quick loops, then pass the final value into your System.out. Now, if during each look you want the saloAnnuale to add the new value to the old, you will need to change your = sign to +=. This is the same as saying saloAnnuale = saloAnnuale + (saldo + valoreInteresse);

Comment: @Ageoffan: Can't believe I hadn't upvoted this a while back; fixed that now. You're a saint to persist.

Comment: Much appreciated. I want to help him understand how loops and variables work as those things come in very handy later on.

Comment: @Monok and what did it give you before? What do you want it to give you? To me it seems as though your code worked, what it did is that it kept adding the new value and then printed it at the end. So, for example. if I had a code that looped 5 times doing x += 5, where x = 0 before the loop. What will get is: 0+5, 5+5, 10+5, 15+5, 20+5. This is because each time the x was updated. And thus was doing x = x +5.

Comment: But I am trying to understand. I've read and tried to understood every answer. I've tested every single line of code you gave me, and just told you that not a single one solved my problem, still...why are you mad at me? What am I doing wrong while talking with you? What's wrong?

Comment: @Ageoffan: Which is fantastic of you, but at this point, this is no longer remotely appropriate for SO's format and is likely to get deleted.

Comment: I've already asked for the deletion of this question, I know that this is not appropriate since lots of comments ago...I just want to say something: sorry for the trouble I'm causing, but this is the third question on this website, and this feedback was horrible...I'm totally scared. I don't know what's wrong with my question, what was wrong, and with my attitude or comments, I just spoke calm and you all started to attack me, and I'm litterally shivering here...no, this is no joke. Please, be kind. I just wanted to learn, and now my mind is in full chaos...

Comment: It is all good, don't worry. On the web it is hard to truly see the person's emotion. And none of us attacked. Anyway, what is the expected result of your code?

Comment: I don't even know anymore. I've just deleted it, and I won't ever try this exercise once again...I'm too scared of it, and I've spent a whole week trying to learn loops, but now I think I will just quit coding if all the people would answer at my questions like that...

Comment: @Monok: Don't be scared. :-) **Do** try to learn from what happened: 1. Post [the **minimum, complete**, code](/help/mcve) that shows the problem. 2. Say *clearly* what result you expect, and what you're getting instead. 3. Brief is best. 4. When people are kind enough to answer or ask for clarification, don't attack them -- don't tell them they're missing the point, or complain about how they're trying to help. You're just starting out; many answering questions here have been doing this a **long** time (doesn't make us perfect!). Be open to being wrong, it's the best way to learn. Regards,

Comment: Exactly what TJ said, don't quit coding. When asking/replying on SO make sure to be very concise and specific, ask for more specific help. For example, this here is a link to a question I had about loops in C, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521746/loop-repeating-itself as you can see, I am pretty newbish as well. Simple error, simple fix.

Comment: I've never attacked anyone, you just came and told me my brakes sucked and that in your 25 years career you saw on me the worst coder ever. Well thanks, I appreciate that as a solution for my loop problem, it really helped!! I am open to being wrong, I'm still wrong, but I still have questions that you made clear you didn't want to answer! Your attitude was the thing that scared the heck of me!! Just stop! Please! @TJ

Comment: Put that aside for now, people simply pointed out that for loop and brackets may be off. With brackets, I would recommend always putting them in the next line. So instead of while(..){. Put your bracket under the while, this means it is easier to keep track of them. But, back to the point of the code, what is the result you want it. That is, why do you believe your code is not working correctly?

Comment: I thought it was wrong, and now that I made some math it is right. Ok. My fault at it. And I do put brackets on the next line, but when I had to write the code here it wouldn't add them on the 'code' part, so I did put them on the upper line. That's it.

Comment: I am glad it worked, not too sure what you mean by the brackets didn't go to the code part. But many things with coding, once you realize the error, are like "OMG, how could I be soo blind" I had this happen to me MANY times.

Comment: When I was writing the question I simply clicked on the two curly brackets button, then pressed Ctrl+V, and the last bracket was outside of the "code part" of the question (How should I call it?). And yeah, it happens to me nearly everytime, but this time I'm still trying to figure why it works that way, but please, let me figure it out by myself, I'm already too much scared...I cried, I don't want to loop the tears again...

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the loop, it's what's *inside* the loop:

```
int conteggio = 1;
do {
    saldoAnnuale = (saldo + valoreInteresse); 
    conteggio++;
    } while (conteggio <= 10);
```

All that does is the same assignment 10 times. The result in `saldoAnnuale` is exactly what it would be if you only did it once.

It's unclear what you want to do, but if (for instance) you wanted to **add** `saldo + valoreInteresse` to `saldoAnnuale` ten times, you'd want `+=`:

```
saldoAnnuale += (saldo + valoreInteresse); 
// ----------^
```

...which is the same as:

```
saldoAnnuale = saldoAnnuale + (saldo + valoreInteresse);
```

Of course, you could just not loop at all and use:

```
saldoAnnuale = (saldo + valoreInteresse) * 10;
```

Comment: You are totally missing the point. I'm talking about loops. The loop doesn't iterate more than a single time. It works the first time, then it stops.

Comment: Your code literally should not work (certainly for loop) if this is actually Java.

Comment: @Ageoffan, yeah, I know it doesn't work...that's why I'm here asking why it doesn't work and how do I need to correct it. But I guess the people are more interested on telling me that I do not know how to write codes, instead of helping. I'm trying to learn Java, and this website should be a learning environment where to ask and get answers, not ask and get judges about something else. I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: @Monok: No. You have had the attention of [several](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) people [who](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) are [seriously](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) helpful. The problem is not in the people who are *reading* the question.

Comment: SO can be toxic, it goes both way. But, read over my answers and the answers of others. Your for loop has a glaring issue with you using , vs ; Also, are you using any IDEs like Eclipse for example? If not, I recommend you do.

Comment: @Ageoffan, using , instead of ; doesn't changed anything. Nor using variables outside the loops. Nor any of the answers above. Answers that I've read and checked one by one, every single one.

Comment: , vs ; will change a lot when dealing with a for loop.

Comment: Tip for future usage of stackoverflow, @Monok, make sure to post your code that is nearest to to the part where you think it is failing. This way people can see what goes on both before and after your code.

Comment: First, I need to loop it. It's an exercise, and I need to solve it with loops. Second, I said it before and it was unclear, so I'm going to try say that again in a different way: saldoAnnuale should update itself with the loop...if saldo = 100, and valoreInteresse is 5, the first iteration gives 105, the second gives 105 + (5% of 105), and so on. I've said it before in math terms, that's the only difference.

Comment: @Monok: I have no idea what all that was meant to mean, and frankly, at this point I couldn't care less. I've told you why the loop doesn't seem to be doing anything useful: The way it's written, repeating what's inside the loop makes no difference to the result. To make a difference, you'd have to use `+=` or similar. </done>

Comment: I've already understood it, I was looking for a suggestion about how to improve it. What's the point of this website, if not helping newbie coders to learn? Thanks for letting me understand that the problem is inside, but I still have to figure out what's wrong. I'll do it by myself, no worries.